Autodesk Fusion Programmatic Material Property and Light Manipulation
Using Fusion (formerly Fusion 360) python scripting, I am trying to generate some orthographic and isometric views as .pngs given a .step file.
This is what I have so far (these are 2 of the 4 images generated):


I am having trouble with two things:

Programmatically changing the RGB color and the roughness setting of this CAD object
Programmatically turning off the shadows on the ground and near the edges and bends of the object

I have attempted to solve both of these by consulting the docs, as you will see in my script, to no avail. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. Code is commented by AI for readability.
import adsk.core, adsk.fusion, adsk.cam, os, traceback

def run(context):
    ui = None
    try:
        app = adsk.core.Application.get()
        ui = app.userInterface
        design = app.activeProduct
        importManager = app.importManager

        # Define file path and output directory
        file_path = r'pathtostep.step'
        output_folder = r'outputpath'

        # Import the STEP file
        stepOptions = importManager.createSTEPImportOptions(file_path)
        rootComp = design.rootComponent
        importManager.importToTarget(stepOptions, rootComp)

        # Load a local material library and get an appearance
        materialLibs = app.materialLibraries
        matLib = materialLibs.load(r'pathto\APISampleMaterialLibrary2.adsklib')
        appear = matLib.appearances.itemByName("Steel - Satin")  # Adjust appearance name as necessary

        # Copy the appearance into the design
        newAppear = design.appearances.addByCopy(appear, f'{appear.name}_Copied')

        # Apply the appearance to all bodies
        allBodies = rootComp.bRepBodies
        for body in allBodies:
            body.appearance = newAppear

        # Setup camera
        camera = app.activeViewport.camera
        camera.cameraType = adsk.core.CameraTypes.OrthographicCameraType

        # Define views
        views = {
            'Front': adsk.core.ViewOrientations.FrontViewOrientation,
            'Top': adsk.core.ViewOrientations.TopViewOrientation,
            'Right': adsk.core.ViewOrientations.RightViewOrientation,
            'Iso': adsk.core.ViewOrientations.IsoTopRightViewOrientation
        }

        # Adjust scene settings for no specular reflections and no shadows
        renderManager = design.renderManager
        sceneSettings = renderManager.sceneSettings
        sceneSettings.backgroundSolidColor = adsk.core.Color.create(255, 255, 255, 0)  # White background
        sceneSettings.ambientLightIntensity = 0.8
        sceneSettings.reflectionsEnabled = False
        sceneSettings.shadowsEnabled = False

        # Process each view
        for view_name, orientation in views.items():
            camera.viewOrientation = orientation
            app.activeViewport.camera = camera
            app.activeViewport.refresh()
            app.activeViewport.fit()

            sceneSettings.shadowsEnabled = False

            # Save images
            image_path = os.path.join(output_folder, f"{view_name}_render.png")
            app.activeViewport.saveAsImageFile(image_path, 384, 384)

    except Exception as e:
        if ui:
            ui.messageBox('Failed:\n{}'.format(traceback.format_exc()))

